# Regex Pattern doesn't work using look behind without validating the fixed-width pattern

Tags: python, regex

I need to find a regex that will extract the city name from strings below.
The order of string is the restaurant name, address, city, phone, cuisine type

- `Chinois on Main 2709 Main St. Santa Monica 310-392-9025 Pacific New Wave`
- `Benita's Frites 1433 Third St. Promenade Santa Monica 310-458-2889 Fast Food`
- `Indo Cafe 10428 1/2 National Blvd. LA 310-815-1290 Indonesian`
- `Diaghilev 1020 N. San Vicente Blvd. W. Hollywood 310-854-1111 Russian`
- `Jody Maroni's Sausage Kingdom 2011 Ocean Front Walk Venice 310-306-1995 Hot Dogs`

I tried this regex, but it doesn't work:

```
zagat['city'] = zagat['raw'].str.extract("""
    ((?<=Ave.|Rd.|St.|Blvd.|Dr.|Way.|Pl.|Ln.|Ct.|Beach|Way ).+(?=...-...-....))
    """, expand=True)
```

Can you help?

Comment: You do not need positive lookbehinds in Pandas `extract` as it only outputs captured substrings.

Comment: You'll need to escape your dots, `\.` to match literal dots, otherwise `.` means any character.

Comment: Try `.extract(r'(?:(?:Ave|Rd|St|Blvd|Dr|Way|Pl|Ln|Ct)\.|Beach|Way|Walk)\s*(.+?)\s*\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
rx = r'(?:(?:Ave|Rd|St|Blvd|Dr|Way|Pl|Ln|Ct)\.|Beach|Way|Walk)\s*(.+?)\s*\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}'
zagat['city'] = zagat['raw'].str.extract(rx, expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NoyCDT/1)

**Details**

- `(?:(?:Ave|Rd|St|Blvd|Dr|Way|Pl|Ln|Ct)\.|Beach|Way|Walk)` - `Ave`, `Rd`, `St`, `Blvd`, `Dr`, `Way`, `Pl`, `Ln` or `Ct` followed with `.` or `Beach`, `Way` or `Walk`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.+?)` - Group 1 (this value will be returned by `.extract`): any one or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}` - 3 digits, `-`, 3 digits, `-` and 4 digits.